# LSTM for Regression (in Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I want to implement some LSTM model in Tensorflow. I think I understood the tutorials fairly well. In those input data was given in the form of words, which were embedded into a continous vector space (which has several advantages). 
I now want to make an LSTM to predict a series of contionous numbers and do not know what is the best approach to that. 
Should I discretize my input range, thus effectively get a classification problem with a number of classes and use the embedding desribed before, or stick to the continous numbers and do regression? In that case I just in each time step pass one feature to the model, namely the continous number?

Answer (score 0):

Here's two example you may find helpful.

https://github.com/MorvanZhou/tutorials/blob/master/tensorflowTUT/tf20_RNN2.2/full_code.py

http://mourafiq.com/2016/05/15/predicting-sequences-using-rnn-in-tensorflow.html

You can just use regression. However, if your input is forever long, you need to fix size sequences.